# Entity Framework Conflicting changes to the role of the relationship have been detected

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho 2 objetos que utilizam um terceiro em comum e estou com um problema na rotina:

1) Criando um novo Fabricante

```
var fab = new Fabricante();
DBSet.Add(fab)   
//Sem SaveChanges
```

Em seguida buscando o item existente e criando um novo, sendo que ambos utilizam o mesmo fabricante ainda não salvo

```
var ItemProcesso = GetItem(1)
ItemProcesso.Fabricante = fab;

var adc = new Adicao()
adc.Fabricante = fab;
ItemProcesso.Adicao = adc;
```

Agora antes de salvar preciso saber quais campos estão sendo alterados do 
ItemProcesso então e é nesse momento que ocorre o erro abaixo:

```
var entryPro = Context.Entry(entity);
```

Erro: *Conflicting changes to the role 'ItemProcesso_Fabricante_Target' of the relationship 'Portal.Infra.Data.Contexto.ItemProcesso_Fabricante' have been detected.*

Agora se comento uma das 2 abaixo o problema não ocorre.

```
ItemProcesso.Fabricante = fab;
adc.Fabricante = fab;
```

OBS: se passo o FabricanteId (objeto já salvo) o problema não ocorre

Alguém sabe se existe alguma forma de realizar esta operação sem erro? 
dica sugestões também serão bem vindas.

Comment: Acredito que é necessario mesmo salvar o fabricante antes de usá-lo como relacionamento nos dois outros indivíduos. Nesse caso, você faria uma transação de contexto para só efetivar as alterações se tudo desse certo. Tecnicamente não sei qual seria a justificativa, tem que ver na documentação do entity framework o que ele fala sobre essas situações, mas eu apostaria que o mecanismo dele está usando o relacionamento da nova instância com a entidade existente para inferir quantos registros de `Fabricante` deve ir para o banco.

Comment: Se minha linha de raciocínio não estiver errada, o erro tambem **não deve acontecer** se você usar duas instâncias diferentes no relacionamento, mas também dois registros serão criados no banco.